# How to match new StackTrace to throw Exception.StackTrace

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, exception, stack-trace

I'm trying to get a stacktrace without throwing an exception, and it works (human readable), the only problem I have is the formatting is different between the 2 methods. This is an issue I have with Unity, because it parses the format from throw to open VS to the associated line #. So if I use a new StackTrace, the format is off and double clicking a log in Unity does nothing. How can I get a new stacktrace to match throw's stacktrace format?

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        string throwTrace = null;
        string newTrace = null;
        try
        {
            newTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(0, true).ToString();
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throwTrace = e.StackTrace;
        }
        Debug.Log("throwTrace: {" + throwTrace + "}");
        Debug.Log("newTrace: {" + newTrace + "}");

    }
}
```

--

```
throwTrace: {  at TestScript.Awake () [0x00013] in /Users/lol_tim/New Unity Project/Assets/TestScript.cs:17 }

newTrace: {   at TestScript.Awake() in /Users/lol_tim/New Unity Project/Assets/TestScript.cs:line 16}
```

Comment: 2 years later... apparently this was only an issue in Unity's .Net 3.5 runtime. This was fixed with the .Net 4.x runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can get the double-click to work by substituting a gibberish code (not really sure what that's used for) and realigning the formatting to match, at least in english culture. I'm not sure if this works with non-english cultures (I tried changing my culture before running this code, but everything still came out in english for some reason). Of course this is extremely ugly and I wish there was a better way to do it.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(0, true).ToString());
sb.Remove(0, 1);
sb.Append(" ");
sb.Replace("(", " (");
sb.Replace(") in", ") [0x00000] in");
sb.Replace("\n ", " \n");
sb.Replace("line ", string.Empty);
newTrace = sb.ToString();
```